# Meaning of a stem extending to both sides of a notehead

Tags: piano, notation, chords

A piano part of a big band arrangement uses notation where chords are marked and stems extend to both sides of noteheads:

[image: Extended stems]

My guess is that this is marking the highest note of the chord to play, as opposed to (more conventional) notation that only gives the chords and the rhythm.

Could you confirm if my assumption is right? Is this commonly used notation?

Comment: Could it be multiple voices with the same note?

Comment: I can confirm that this is in no way a standard notation. I've played hundreds of big-band charts and never seen this.

Comment: @Aaron Maybe it's a regional thing: I've often seen it.

Comment: @PiedPiper - so have I, but never seen that before.

Comment: @PiedPiper In a published chart?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, in a published chart. I have an example on my music stand right now.

Comment: @PiedPiper Fair enough.

Comment: This has been a form of shorthand in jazz and pop for some time. It is more detailed than just chords or chords and rhythm by specifying the top note of the voicing but allowing the chording instrument freedom to select their own voicings.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy - still never met it! As it stands, there appears to be two options as to the actual rhythm needed, stems up, or stems down. Or trying to decode the little dots on top. None of which is intuitive - to me! Understand top note must be D, though...

Comment: @Tim There really are not two options, the D is the top note of the chord. You don’t put a down stem on the right side of a note. Think of the down stem as a “fill in the blank” voicing. The dots are staccato markings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is used occasionally and means exactly what you think it does: play those chords in that rhythm with those top notes. The exact voicing is up to the player.

Here's another example that's more explicit about the voicings:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not uncommon in guitar or keyboard parts, or maybe in a 'short score' where all the instrument parts are condensed onto one or more staves.   Yes, it means to play block chords under the given melody.